# SetBinding and CheckBox value

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am not sure if I have use `"CheckedValue"` here...

Or I have to use `"IsCheckedValue"` ?

```
Dim bndg_3 As New Binding("CheckedValue")
bndg_3.Source = checkbox1
MyCtrl.SetBinding(MyCtrl.CanMoveProperty, bndg_3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HA!

I found it!

```
Dim bndg_3 As New Binding("IsChecked")
bndg_3.Source = checkbox1
MyCtrl.SetBinding(MyCtrl.CanMoveProperty, bndg_3)
```